# VSCode gives "incomplete type" messages (about timespec) I can't repeat using GCC command--how to solve this?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc, timespec

Win64, VSCode set to use GCC to compile .C file.

I'm not able to get any similar warning from GCC on the command line, despite trying many options, and the code compiles and runs fine. Is intellisense going OTT?

The first error is defining tim, a timespec for nanosleep() in time.h and the only quick hint in VSCode is "disable error squiggles" :-)

(I also get errors on the code setting members of the stucture. "incomplete class type "struct timespec" is not allowed")

VSCode lists first problem as "incomplete type is not allowed" and a right-click lets me copy:-

```
[{
    "resource": "/C:/Users/Roopy/source/c/temp/temptemp.c",
    "owner": "C/C++: IntelliSense",
    "code": "70",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "incomplete type is not allowed",
    "source": "C/C++",
    "startLineNumber": 5,
    "startColumn": 21,
    "endLineNumber": 5,
    "endColumn": 24
}]
```

example code:-
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>         /* for timespec, nanosleep() */

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct timespec tim = {3,500000000L};
    
    tim.tv_sec =  2;
    tim.tv_nsec = 500000000L; /* 0.5 sec */
    
    puts("Starting nanosleep()...");
    fflush(stdin);
    if (nanosleep(&tim,&tim) < 0 ) {
      puts("nanosleep() failed.");
      return -1;
    }
    puts("Stopping.");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `struct timespec` and `nanosleep` are not a part of the C language. They are a part of POSIX. Intellisense doesn't necessarily know about these. What is your `intelliSenseMode` in `c_cpp_properties.json`? Try setting to `clang-x64` or `gcc-x64`.

Comment: I can see that. But the way POSIX compliance is implemented must be C, surely? 

I don't see c_cpp_properties.json but I'll try VSCode settings to create one.

I think my main surprise is that I'm used to other languages, where the compiler/assembler docs tell you where macros/include files come from, and the compiler can produce a long listing, where "timespec tim;" is followed by a chain of resulting code that shows where the problem actually is!

This feels like inspired guesswork, something I'm not so good at...

Comment: Your C compiler doesn't have a problem with it, Intellisense does. Intellisense does not necessarily see the same include files your compiler sees.

Comment: I think this is boiling down to a choice of suitably cautious GCC options that I'll be told of build problems. The rest I'll have to find with testing.